# How to create and destroy cookie in Laravel 5.7?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am a novice in Laravel, I have made a simple hello program in Laravel and I want to use a cookie in my program. How do I create and delete a cookie in Laravel?
Also, how do I set session in Laravel?

Comment: Welcome to So, Please post your code !

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Set cookie:
`Cookie::queue(Cookie::make('cookieName', 'value', $minutes));`

Get cookie:
`$value = $request->cookie('cookieName');`
or
`$value = Cookie::get('cookieName');`

Forget/remove cookie: 
`Cookie::queue(Cookie::forget('cookieName'));`

Check if cookie exist:
`Cookie::has('cookiename');` or `$request->hasCookie('cookiename')` will return true or false

For more detail, you can refer to the documentation:

- https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests#cookies
- https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Contracts/Cookie/Factory.html

Comment: Ok sir but i can't think that can i make new controller for this or where i set cookie and get cookie and forget cookie (in controller, in views, in routes)

Comment: actually you can set,get,forget cookie in all controller, views and routes.... but it is better/practical/recommended to set,get,forget cookie only in Controller..

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::post("/createcookie",function(Request $request){
    //let us create cookie
    $name = $request->txtname;
    $value  = $request->txtvalue;
    $minute = $request->txtminute;
    $response = new Response("Cookie created $name with  $value for duration $minute");
    return $response->withCookie(cookie($name,$value,$minute));
});

Route::get("/getcookie/{name}",function(Request $request,$name){
    $value = $request->cookie($name);
    ///echo "Value of $name cookie is $value";
    return view("getcookie")->with("name",$name);
});


Route::get("/deletecookie/{name}",function(Request $request,$name)
{
    $response = new Response("Cookie $name deleted successfully");
    return $response->withCookie(cookie($name,null,0));
});
```